# What is the best way to package Elixir CLI application?

Tags: erlang, elixir, command-line-interface, beam

Suppose I have a CLI application with subcommands and arguments (like `application foo --bar baz`). How can I package it for distribution without requiring user to install Erlang?

I know there's `mix escript` Mix task, but it builds a binary that requires Erlang to be installed, also Mix reference states that escripts should be used only for development purposes.
`mix release`, however, produces redundant shell scripts that I don't want to see in dist.

So, is there a way to make a standalone distributable of an Elixir CLI application?

P. S. This is actually my first experience with Elixir (and the whole Erlang ecosystem)

Answer (score 4):

Elixir applications can be packaged as [Erlang releases](https://erlang.org/doc/design_principles/release_structure.html), see also [here](https://adoptingerlang.org/docs/production/releases/). These can include Erlang VM. Elixir since 1.9 supports building releases without extra tooling, using included mix task `mix release` - please check the documentation for greasy details: https://hexdocs.pm/mix/Mix.Tasks.Release.html

You might benefit from a quick look at this blog post for inspiration and conceptual overview, noticing that for simple CLI app it is much simpler: https://www.cogini.com/blog/best-practices-for-deploying-elixir-apps/

Comment: As I understood, `mix release` used more for applications that should run as a service, like Web-server. It generates shell scripts I don't need. I have seen somewhere that it is possible to use `app eval SomeModule.main` to run an application, but this means that I should write another shell script to launch shell script to launch the application. That's weird. I thought that there can be another mix task that will generate shell scripts for CLI applications (like ones that are used by Elixir CLI tools).

Comment: (1/2) I proposed to use Erlang release because the question asked for a way to package elixir app without requiring the user to install erlang. Elixir by necessity requires Erlang, so I thought it should be packaged along with the app to make it easier for the target user. Typical Erlang app is more complicated (distributed, concurrent, persistent, error resilient, configurable) than a simple CLI app that is run and then just quits, so Erlang release surely will take care of more concerns than you need.

Comment: (2/2) Anyway there are lots of ways to control how the release (`mix release` executing `Mix.Tasks.Release`) is done, for example removing stuff you do not need by `steps` configuration, and this is where Broadway as proposed in another answer, also plugs in.

Answer (score 2):

[Bakeware](https://github.com/bake-bake-bake/bakeware) generates a single executable file.

They have added a CLI app example [here](https://github.com/bake-bake-bake/bakeware/tree/main/examples/simple_script).

Comment: This seems to be the best solution, however, it does not now support Windows. Sadly, I need the application to work on Windows, so this does not work for me...

Comment: Just an update from the future, it looks like Bakeware supports windows now